# Jquery - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: gallery/(3).jpg

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a website and now i program an elevator in jQuery. My problem is, that, I have been created a lot of code and after add a script to my links in navigation it works, but after clicking on photo i get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: gallery/(3).jpg
```

here's the code of elevator:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a, button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
```

When i remove this code, error is not showing any more.

Comment: Sounds like the `href` attribute of your button contains `gallery/(3).jpg`. That's not a valid CSS selector.

Comment: Error shows when i load lightbox script from image

Comment: Okay...? I've already told you what the problem with your code is. It isn't helpful to tell me *when* you're getting the problem.

Comment: Yup I found it, i have <a href> in my gallery thumbnails and i just change the selector from

'a, button' to selector a in header like: '.navigation a'

You inspired me and i fix that :) hehe thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help!